# What does GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_application_run: assertion 'acquired_context' failed mean

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

I'm upgrading a very large flight simulation project to GTKMM 3 from 2.4.  When running the Gtk::Application with a Gtk::ApplicationWindow on a separate thread from the main simulation thread, we receive multiple warnings:

```
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_application_run: assertion 'acquired_context' failed
```

But the GTK window does show and is functional.  The code is compiled in debug mode.
Thanks

Comment: There are a number of assertions in the gtkmm (& comp libraries) that warn about non-breaking runtime issues. You definitely need to gdb debug the app and backtrace until you find the error. The [following page](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html) might help you with setting the appropriate flags. All in all, your question is too broad for any good answer. You might want to edit it with some code after some debugging (if you don't already fix it).

Comment: the similar problem

~ >>> pamac-manager                                                            
    ** Message: 15:01:30.953: flatpak_plugin.vala:345: refreshing flathub appstream data

(pamac-manager:4361): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:01:31.204: g_application_run: assertion 'acquired_context' failed

Answer (score 2):

solved for me:

```
sudo pacman --overwrite="*" -S flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak update
```

Comment: worked for me. how does it work though??